# Forbidden.RiskControl Error while Launching Linux Instance on AliBaba Cloud

Tags: java, alibaba-cloud

I'm trying to launch linux instance with user data script using the java SDK 
But i'm getting this error:

```
Forbidden.RiskControl, This operation is forbidden by Aliyun RiskControl system
```

Any idea?

This is my code:

```
CommonRequest commonRequest = new CommonRequest(); 
commonRequest.setDomain("ecs.aliyuncs.com"); 
commonRequest.setMethod(MethodType.POST); 
commonRequest.setVersion("2014-05-26"); 
commonRequest.setAction("RunInstances"); 
commonRequest.setRegionId("us-west-1"); 
commonRequest.putBodyParameter("ImageId", "centos_6_09_64_20G_alibase_20180326.vhd"); 
commonRequest.putBodyParameter("InstanceType", "ecs.sn1.medium"); 
commonRequest.putBodyParameter("SecurityGroupId", "sg-1234"); 
commonRequest.putBodyParameter("VSwitchId", "vsw-1234"); 
commonRequest.putBodyParameter("KeyPairName", "key-pair"); 
commonRequest.putBodyParameter("InternetMaxBandwidthOut", 1); 
commonRequest.putBodyParameter("UserData", "IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gNCg0KZWNobyAiaGVsbG8iID4gL3RtcC9maWxlMS50eHQNCmVjaG8gImhlbGxvIiA+IGZpbGUxLnR4dA=="); 

CommonResponse commonResponse = client2.getCommonResponse(commonRequest);
```

Comment: Contact AliBaba support, that seems to be a common answer when doing a google search.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to open a new support ticket in the Alibaba Console.

Alibaba will ask you for your identity paperwork such a driver's license or passport. Just include a photocopy when you open the ticket to speed things up. Also make sure that your credit card has credit available. I am an Alibaba Cloud MVP and this has happened to me (as an MVP).